# Dereferencing pointers to make a copy of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm currently trying to copy one array to another (values 200 - 299 to be specific) while dereferencing pointers.

```
*point = &array2[100]; //points to location 100 in array2, which holds numbers 100-300
```

Couldn't I just use a for loop to start where the pointer starts, and then set both arrays equal to each other?

```
for(i = *point; i < 300; i++){
    array2 = array;
}
```

It says to dereference my pointer, so I'd use something like *(point + a number), but I'm not exactly sure what to do. An example or link to an example would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you have to write the code yourself?  [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) will let you copy one range to another

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, I have to write the code myself, so I can't use std::copy. I have to copy array2 to the first array while dereferencing my pointer, so using point[0], point[1], etc is not allowed

Comment: `pointer[index]` *IS* dereferencing the `pointer`, it is identical to `*(pointer + index)`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Right. I just can't figure out how to copy the array using that though

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this:

```
for (int *p = array1 + 200, *q = array2 + 200; p < array1 + 300; ++p, ++q)
{
    *q = *p;
}
```

Comment: are p and q supposed to be new pointers, or is p supposed to be the pointer I already established?

Comment: also I didn't mention it, but I'm copying values 200 - 299 into the first array

Comment: Yes, `p` and `q` are new pointers.  You can call them whatever you want.  I updated the answer to only copy the last 100 elements.

Comment: Alright, makes sense. I'm running the code and it's giving me the memory addresses. If I wanted to print out the actual numbers, would I do something like nums = *q, and then cout << nums ?

Comment: Yes, or just `cout << *q;`  Inside the loop, that is.